# Spring session login

Tags: java, spring, session

I would like to build a web application based on [this example](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/spring-session).

What I understood from this example is that you build 2 applications:
A UI application containing the web pages where you can login to get a token and a resource application where you ask for data using your token.

My question is where is the login check done?
The **application.yml** file defines the password "**password**" for the user "**user**"

```
security:
  user:
    password: password
```

But this file is never mentioned neither in **UIApplication.java** file or in any other file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class UiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .logout().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html", "/pages/home.html", "/pages/login.html", "/").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/token")
    public Map<String,String> token(HttpSession session) {
        return Collections.singletonMap("token", session.getId());
    }

}
```

However it works: when I login using "user" and "password" login succeeds, when I use different credentials, it fails.
Is it some high level Spring layer dealing with that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little bit of a confusing example that you have picked because it uses Angular for login. So it is sending off the request using AngularJS.

To break it down, first let's have a look at the [`login.html`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/spring-session/ui/src/main/resources/static/login.html) page:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="controller.login()">
```

So when we submit, we require the `controller.login()` method call, this is defined in the [`hello.js`](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/spring-session/ui/src/main/resources/static/js/hello.js) file.

```
}).when('/login', {
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'navigation',
        controllerAs : 'controller'
```

Here we delegate requests sent to `/login` and map that to our `navigation` controller. If you go ahead in the `hello.js` script you'll see the following:

```
.controller('navigation',
    ...
    var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

        var headers = credentials ? {
            authorization : "Basic "
                    + btoa(credentials.username + ":"
                            + credentials.password)
        } : {};

        $http.get('user', {
                ...
```

Here, we use make a `GET` request to `/user`. And if you take a look at the [controller](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/spring-session/ui/src/main/java/demo/UiApplication.java), you'll see that there is a User Principle being returned which is then checked against credentials.

The controller requires a User principle to be passed in for verification which is being built up in the `headers` part of the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) request.

I would recommend using [this example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-mvc-login) if you are new to Spring Security and want to start off with something more Java oriented and simple.

### Edit

It should also be noted that the user object is being created by the Spring `application.yml` as you said it is formed of the following:

```
security:
  user:
    password: password
```

This is equivalent to:

```
security.user.password="password"
```

Reference to the `application.yml` appendix can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

So in essence, the yml file is creating a User with the given password which can be retrieved by the Principle. [Take a look at the huge guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/) written by Spring that explains the project built in that repo you are looking at, step by step.

Comment: So credentials file is parsed by Angular/javascript?

Comment: @user2436719 I've edited my post for some more clarity.

Comment: OK, I understand it better now, thanks. Yes the link to Spring guide is the tutorial I was following, and I thought that the Spring-session section fitted my needs in terms of security and simplicity...